# Multiple ajax calls from an array without blocking UI

Tags: php, ajax

This is how i am rendering my dashboard.

1. Load allowed widget names as per role and permission. Now, i have a list of function names as follows.

   var widgetnames = ['widget1', 'widget2','widget3'];

Functions for executing all widgets are already defined.

```
function widget1(){ $.ajax(...); }
function widget2(){ $.ajax(...); } 
function widget3(){ $.ajax(...); }
```

2. Execute `widgetnames` from the array as follows.

   $.each(widgetnames, function(index, fn){ 
     if ($.isFunction(window[fn])){ windowfn; }
   });

This is working smoothly with `SYNCHRONOUS AJAX` calls

**Issue**

Here the UI element freezes until all functions in `widgetnames` are executed. Is there any possible solution ? Asynchronous AJAX calls can not be adopted due to some reasons.

Comment: what are those reasons? They are probably wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of Deferred / Promises action to help here.

In this simple use case, you can use jQuery's $.when() method, which takes a list of these "Deferred" objects (All jQuery Ajax methods return Deferred objects) and then provides a single callback.

```
$.when(

  // Deferred object (probably Ajax request),

  // Deferred object (probably Ajax request),

  // Deferred object (probably Ajax request)

).then(function() {

  // All have been resolved (or rejected), do your thing

});
```